# Display image one at a time?

Tags: javascript, image, jsp

Here is a JSP code, where urls contain urls to images. What I want to do, is to display images one at a time.  Instead this code, places 'all' the image on the same page left to right, and top to bottom. How to display image one at a time and not all in the same page ?

```
<body>

<% List<String> urls = (List)request.getAttribute("url"); %>

<% for (int i = 0; i < urls.size();i++) {%>
<img src = <%= urls.get(i) %> style="width:304px;height:228px;"></img>
<% } %>

</body>
```

Comment: You need a JavaScript Solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+slide+show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, I would suggest to stop using `scriplets <%%>` and use expression language `${yourExpression}` and JSTL tags.

To implement your requirement you need to do it in javascript, not on the server side. You could use for example `setTimeout(addImageFn, 1000)` in javascript to inject/make visible every images with some delay you want (every second etc)